# Overlaying many curves in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't know how to replicate the add=TRUE argument  in the curve() function in ggplot2?

Suppose I have this plot

```
     testfn<-function(x,a){
        sin(x-a)
    }

    for(i in 1:10){
        curve(testfn(x,i),add=TRUE,xlim=c(-5,5))
    }
```

How do I do this in ggplot2 without having to manually add 10 +stat_function()s?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of calls to `stat_function` using `lapply`

eg

```
 library(ggplot2)
# the base plot (with x limits)
xlim <- c(-5,5)
baseplot <- ggplot(data.frame(x = xlim), aes(x=x))

# the function
testfn <- function(x,a){sin(x-a)}
# a list of 10 calls (a = 1,...10)
list_fn <- lapply(seq_len(10), function(a){
  stat_function(fun = testfn, args = list(a=a))
})
# the plot
baseplot + list_fn
```

[image]